# Convert a line shapefile to a raster layer and preserve values

Tags: r, raster, spatial, r-sf

I have an `sf` object that contains road geoms and road types (e.g. secondary, highway, cycleway, etc.):

(code taken from [this blog post](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html))

```
library(osmdata)
library(tidyverse)

muenster <- 
  opq(bbox =  c(7.61, 51.954, 7.636, 51.968)) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway') %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  osm_poly2line()

muenster_center <- muenster$osm_lines %>% 
  dplyr::select(highway)
```

I want to convert this shapefile to a raster file where the road types are preserved so that I can calculate cost paths.

Comment: see the rasterize function in the raster package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.4-5/topics/rasterize. Alternatively, you can also use the fasterize version - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fasterize/versions/1.0.3/topics/fasterize

Comment: You may also want to check the [`st_network_cost()`](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/routing.html#retrieving-an-od-cost-matrix-1) function in [`sfnetworks`](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/index.html) which is linked with the blog post you mentioned. It does not provide a raster file, but maybe it can still be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks both -- this might be out of the scope of this post, but my primary goal is to figure out an optimum path between two points while factoring in road quality, topology, etc. Using shapefiles and the ``st_network_cost`` function as suggested, I am unable to account for non-road routes, so I think this is a raster-based problem. The question now becomes how to incorporate roads, topology, etc. into this cost function.

Comment: @PabloHerrerosCantis the fasterize function does not work for lines, only polygons. See my answer for a faster rasterize for lines using the stars package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE** Use `terra` which is the replacement for the `raster` package and it will be much faster and you won't need stars. See Robert's answer

As you may have noticed rasterize is quite slow for large data sets. I created a function that wraps around `stars::st_rasterize` so that it takes a RasterLayer and sf and returns a RasterLayer

```r
rasterizeLine <- function(sfLine, rast, value){
  # rasterize roads to template
  tmplt <- stars::st_as_stars(sf::st_bbox(rast), nx = raster::ncol(rast),
                              ny = raster::nrow(rast), values = value)
  
  rastLine <- stars::st_rasterize(sfLine,
                                  template = tmplt,
                                  options = "ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE") %>%
    as("Raster")
  
  return(rastLine)
}

library(osmdata)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

muenster <- 
  opq(bbox =  c(7.61, 51.954, 7.636, 51.968)) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway') %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  osm_poly2line()

muenster_center <- muenster$osm_lines %>% 
  select(highway) %>% 
  # Note you have to turn it into a factor for stars to use that column and it
  # has to be the first column
  mutate(highway = as.factor(highway))

r <- raster::raster(muenster_center, ncol=1000, nrow=1000)

system.time({
  muenster_rast <- rasterizeLine(muenster_center, r, NA)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.09    0.07    0.15 

system.time({
  muenster_rast2 <- raster::rasterize(muenster_center, r, "highway")
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 207.56    0.06  208.75

raster::freq(muenster_rast - muenster_rast2)
#      value  count
# [1,]    -2      1
# [2,]     0  63676
# [3,]    NA 936323
```

Output looks very similar between the two but the version that uses stars is much faster!

Answer (score 2):

With `terra` it goes like this

```
library(osmdata)

muenster <- 
  opq(bbox =  c(7.61, 51.954, 7.636, 51.968)) |>
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway') |>
  osmdata_sf() |> 
  osm_poly2line()

muenster_center <- muenster$osm_lines["highway"]

library(terra)

v <- vect(muenster_center)
r <- rast(v, resolution=1/12000)

x <- rasterize(v, r, "highway")
plot(x)
```

[image]

If you need a RasterLayer you can do

```
r <- raster::raster(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a spatial lines object:

```
muenster_center <- as(muenster_center, "Spatial")
```

Turn highway variable into a factor:

```
muenster_center@data$highway <- as.factor(muenster_center@data$highway)
```

Create a raster (ncol + nrow define the granularity of the raster)

```
r <- raster(muenster_center, ncol=1000, nrow=1000)    
m_ras <- rasterize(muenster_center, r, "highway")
```

Running `plot(m_ras)` produces the image below:

[image]

You can then use the `shortestPath` command from the `gdistance` package to calculate cost paths.